# SQL Find number of disctint date's in datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to find the amount of unique date's in an SQL Query, however my date column is formatted as date time.

Normally for this query I'd use this SQL

```
    SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT `datetime`) AS 'count'
FROM
    `TableName`
```

However this obvisouly gives all the unique times as well.

How best can I only utilise the date portion of this SQL query.

Comment: `DATE(datetime)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(datetime)) AS 'count'
FROM `TableName`
```